# Elastic search is not returning expected results for term query

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

This is how ,my article data looks in elastic search

```
id:123,
title:xyz,
keywords:"Test Example"


id:124,
title:xyzz,
keywords:"Test Example|test1"
```

When a keyword is clicked on the front end,say for example: 'Test Example' then i should get articles having that keyword ( i should get above two articles as my results).But i am getting only first article as my result and below is my mapping:

```
"keywords":
{
"type":"string",
"index":"not_analysed"
}
```

How can i get both articles in search results?Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`Term Query` searches for exact terms. That's why when you search for `Test Example` you  get only one result, as there is only one record that exactly matches `Test Example`. If you want both the results you need to use something like [match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) or [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html). You can use `query_string` like:

```
{
"query": {
    "query_string": {
       "default_field": "keywords",
        "query": "Test Example*"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to Query with query_string,term query search only for exact term.

Answer (score 0):

You set your `keywords` field to `not_analyzed`: if you want the field to be searchable you should remove the `index` clause like so

```
"keywords": {
    "type":"string"
}
```

Searching over this field with a `match` query, anyway, will return results containing a superset of the provided query: searching for `test` will return both documents even though the tag is actually `Test Example`.

---

If you can change your documents to something like this

```
id:123,
title:xyz,
keywords:"Test Example"


id:124,
title:xyzz,
keywords: ["Test Example", "test1"]
```

you can use your original mapping with `"index":"not_analysed"` and a [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) will return only documents containing exactly the tag you were looking for.

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "keywords": "test1"
    }
  }
}
```

Another option to accomplish the same result is to use a [pattern tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-tokenizer.html) to split your tag string on the `|` character to accomplish the same result

```
  "tokenizer": {
    "split_tags": {
      "type": "pattern",
      "group": "-1",
      "pattern": "\|"
    }
  }
```

Comment: i have added this tokenizer "split_tags": {
      "type": "pattern",
      "group": "0",
      "pattern": "([^|]+)"
    } and i am using this in my mapping ( i have changed index to 'analysed') .It is working for one word keywords.But i am not getting expected results for below scenario :id:123,
title:xyz,
keywords:"test"


id:124,
title:xyzz,
keywords:"Test Example|test"  if i search for 'Test Example',then i should get only second article as my result but i am getting two articles as my results :(

Comment: Just adding your `split_tags` tokenizer to the settings is not enough; you should also add a custom analyzer that makes use of the `split_tag` tokenizer. Moreover, in your field you should set `"type": "string", "analyzer": "split_analyzer"`.

Comment: You can use the `_analyze` API to check if your field is analyzed as you expect it to be analyzed ;) https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html

Comment: i have added custom analyser and i am making use of split_tag tokenizer but i didn't mention that in my comment( sorry about that).Analyser looks like this "split_tags":{
   "type":"custom",
   "tokenizer":"split_tags",
  "filter":["text_word_delimiter"]
   }

Comment: Did you try `elasticsearch.host:9200/yourindex/_analyze?field=yourfield&text=Test Example|test`? Also, the documentation for the pattern tokenizer mentions "The regular expression should match the token separators, not the tokens themselves.", but it seems like you are matching the tokens themselves - you should change your tokenizer to `{ "type": "pattern", "group": "-1", "pattern": "|" }`

Comment: :yes,here it is 'C:\websites\ServerConfig\ElasticSearch\Articles>curl -XGET "localhost:9200/articlestest/_analyze?pretty=true&field=keywords" -d "AKQA|Campaign Viral Chart"
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "AKQA",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 4,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "CampaignViralChart",
    "start_offset" : 5,
    "end_offset" : 25,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 2
  } ]
}'

Comment: Is this with the tokenizer I suggested or with the one you proposed?

Comment: When i test the field(i can see my keywords are split at '|' (pipe) character but when i run the query for 'Campaign Viral Chart' in elastic search plugin, i don't get any results don't know why.

Comment: For some reason your token is transformed to `CampaignViralChart ` without spaces - do you know why?

Comment: I tried using the tokenizer which you have suggested and tested( keywords got split at every character- (not at pipe character)).So ,i have changed tokenizer to "split_tags": { "type": "pattern", "group": "0", "pattern": "([^|]+)" }

Comment: And i don't know why the analyser is removing whitespaces(i was thinking it  removes by default? not sure)

Comment: Fixed the answer above, please try using the pattern tokenizer as specified there - you need to escape the pipe character for the regex to work properly.

Comment: I have used the above tokenizer.when i run the analysers batch file ,i get 400 error

Answer (score 0):

I have got it working with the following tokenizer:

```
"split_keywords": {
      "type": "pattern",
      "group": "0",
      "pattern": "([^|]+)"
    }
```

Keywords will split at pipe character(below is the example)

```
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "TestExample",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 12,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "test",
    "start_offset" : 13,
    "end_offset" : 17,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 2
  }, {
    "token" : "1",
    "start_offset" : 17,
    "end_offset" : 18,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 3
  }, {
    "token" : "test1",
    "start_offset" : 13,
    "end_offset" : 18,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 3
  } ]
}
```

Now when i search for 'TestExample',i get above two articles.
Thanks a lot for your help :)